# I get FacebookProfile class not found execption in springframework.social.facebook api with maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook, spring, maven

Please any one help me!

The `springframework.social.facebook.api.FacebookProfile` class not found exception is throws using maven build steps.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project server: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/Rajeev Gandhi/Project/server/src/main/java/com/axamit/core/impl/service/social/FacebookSocialServiceImpl.java:[309,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FacebookProfile
[ERROR] location: class com.axamit.core.impl.service.social.FacebookSocialServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/Rajeev Gandhi/Project/server/src/main/java/com/axamit/core/impl/service/social/FacebookSocialServiceImpl.java:[401,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FacebookProfile
[ERROR] location: class com.axamit.core.impl.service.social.FacebookSocialServiceImpl
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

But, the `.m2/repository` the jar file is there. I don't know why it showing the following error.

Comment: Could you please include your pom.xml, your FacebookSocialServiceImpl code and your spring context config?

Answer (score 1):

FacebookProfile has been removed in v2.0.1 and replaced with org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User, which seems to be compatible with FacebookProfile (just a rename I guess).